# Is there any way to build a circuit that acts identically to a redstone repeater?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm looking to build a circuit that acts like a vanilla repeater block in that it repeats the redstone signal, acts as a diode, and allows multiple levels of delay to be set. However, I would like the delay to be configurable via sticky pistons such that I can change the delay remotely through the use of a redstone signal. I would prefer an answer that describes a circuit capable of accomplishing this while being as compact as possible and preferably without using redstone repeater blocks. However, if a design could be simplified through their use, I would appreciate it if it was detailed how such simplification could be accomplished.

Comment: Would somebody clarify why my question might have been downvoted? I feel like a downvote without a comment is just as unclear or not useful as whatever in the question warranted the downvote.

Comment: Was this question answered by whatever you did [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338150/tick-delay-caused-by-hoppers)? If yes, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do know of a way but it is fairly complicated, I'll try to explain though. First, you do know that redstone torches stop items from flowing out of a hopper if the hopper is above, so that means if you make a pulse extender that turns off the redstone torch the item would flow faster than a shorter pulse extender, you could you the pulse extender hooked to a sticky piston with a redstone block on it that would keep the block there then would be toggled by redstone dust out of the redstone block pushed, the more hoppers you have, the slower it is, the longer the pulse extension the faster it is. Another thing, redstone torches need to be under all the hoppers, and you need to make a lever activated comparator clock so that it isn't one pulse, also the longer the comparator clock holds, the faster the item flows through, so if you want items to move very slowly you either decrease the pulse extension or you decrease the time between for comparator clocks. Resulting in you having an adjustable comparator/hopper based repeater, which ticks can be very high.