# Tick delay caused by Hoppers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to answer the question I posted here a couple days ago([Is there any way to build a circuit that acts identically to a redstone repeater?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338081/is-there-any-way-to-build-a-circuit-that-acts-identically-to-a-redstone-repeater)), and I'm attempting to use hoppers to simulate the configurable delay that repeaters allow. However, I'm finding it difficult to come up with a set of hoppers comparable to a repeater. Currently I have a line of four sequential hoppers with a comparator at the end, and when I place an item in the first hopper with the /replaceitem command, there's apparently eight ticks of delay before the comparator at the end powers the redstone lamp following it. I have verified this delay using a repeater setup as detailed in the attached screenshot. My question is, how much delay does each component in the hopper setup, including the command block, the hoppers, and the comparator, contribute to the circuit?[image]

Comment: I think I might have figured it out, but I'd still like someone to verify it for me: I believe that the command block contributes one tick of delay, followed by two for each hopper transfer(for a total of six), and a final tick of delay from the comparator. is that analysis correct?

Comment: Wait, that can't be right, because when I add a fifth hopper it seemingly adds four ticks of delay to the circuit instead of the predicted two.

Comment: EUREKA! Could hoppers potentially transfer items every 3 game ticks? That would work out to 1.5 redstone ticks, which would explain the 12 redstone ticks that occur during the four transfers.

Comment: Nope, with five transfers the total delay is raised to sixteen ticks, and assuming there's a single tick delay for the command block and one for the comparator, that would leave 14 ticks in which the transfers occur, which would translate to 2.8 ticks per transfer.

Comment: [Here](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Hopper#Redstone_component) is a lot of info about the speed of hoppers. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I had read through that page before, but I overlooked the section where it states that a hopper that has an item pushed into it will also start a cool down. I was previously under the impression that a hopper wouldn't start the cool down unless it had initiated the item transfer itself. Thanks for encouraging me to read over it again.

Answer (score 1):

After reading over the wiki page on hoppers again, I discovered that the three tick cool down also applies to hoppers that receive an item regardless of whether or not it initiated the item transfer. I suppose that would put a three tick delay for each transfer except the first one(because of the item being placed into the first hopper by a command). So that makes six ticks for the hopper transfers, one tick for the command, and one tick for the comparator so that it totals out to the target eight ticks.